# Is it PCI compliant to send credit card details to the server without saving them there?

Tags: pci-dss, credit-card

Considering I use SSL the whole process.

I have an IOS client that I want to use to enter the user's credit card details. I want to do the whole charging and processing on the server side, so I send the credit card details to the server where it is being used to process. I don't save the details there on any permanent storage.

Is this okay / enough ?

Comment: Here is the latest PCI-DSS standard https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI_DSS_v3.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  You can not handle PCI without meeting PCI-DSS requirements for handling PCI.  Not storing it just means you don't have to worry about storage requirements, but things like network segmentation and server security still apply, even if it only transits across your server.

Comment: Can you elaborate about the network segmentation part ? A lot of payment SDKs allow you to create tokens on the client just by sending the card details over https to a 3rd party server.

Comment: @Michael - yes, the third party works because the client talks to the third party (who is PCI-DSS compliant) and only non-PCI information is ever shared with the vendor's systems.  This allows them to avoid falling under PCI-DSS.  You could use a similar setup with your iOS application by coordinating through a third party.  Basically, the iOS app would tell your server what it wanted to buy, you would tell the payment service provider what to charge and get a token to give the user, the user's device would then connect to the service provider, complete the purchase and then the service

Comment: provider would either inform you directly or provide the client with a token that could be used as proof of payment.  (An electronic receipt if you will.)

Comment: @AJHenderson I think the iOS app itself would still fall under PCI compliance requirements if it's accepting credit card data  and transmitting it to the payment vendor to receive a  token. I'm not sure if this is what you were suggesting, or if you were suggesting handing off the entire transaction (including accepting the user's credit card) to a payment vendor's application.

Comment: @Johnny - the iOS app is being run by the client.  I don't believe it would fall under PCI requirements for the same reason a web browser does not.  The point of PCI-DSS is to ensure that third parties protect an individual's credit information.  What a person does with their own (by using an application on their phone for example) is not covered.

Comment: Unencrypted local storage for example would be a bad software design, but it wouldn't be a violation of PCI-DSS since it is the customer storing their own information.

Comment: If he's writing his own mobile app that accepts credit card data and sends it to a server for processing (whether his server or someone else's), I don't see how it could escape being defined as a "Payment Application (_Any application that stores, processes, or transmits cardholder data as part of authorization or settlement_)" under PCI. Since he's writing the app, he has to follow PCI  compliance guidelines to protect sensitive cardholder data.

Comment: @Johnny - you aren't reading back far enough.  "PCI DSS requirements apply to organizations and environments where..."  An end user application for the customer is not an organization or environment handling other people's data.  It only handles their own.  The end user can't be an entity involved in payment card processing or you would have to securely store your own credit card information.  Applications in the PCI-DSS sense generally refer to internal use applications for dealing with PCI data and processing.

Answer (score 2):

Difficult to know your exact set up but using language like 'send the credit card details' raises alarms. I'd suggest that fits into the 'Store Process and transmitting' of data. I'd be VERY suspicious of any answer to the contrary and bare in mind 90% plus of businesses that think they don't store data actually do once scanned and tested. Sorry it may not have been the answer you wanted but it's honest

Answer (score 1):

```
PCI DSS applies to all entities ... that store, process or transmit cardholder data.
```

([PCI DSS v2](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/pci_dss_v2.pdf) Introduction)

If you process credit card details, you're subject to PCI.

If you transmit credit card details, you're subject to PCI.

SSL / network encryption is one of the requirements for meeting PCI DSS (Requirement 4).  There are others; you'll need to assess what you're doing in order to determine which you need to pay attention to.  You should look at the [Self Assessment Questionnaires](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/merchants/self_assessment_form.php) to determine which scope likely applies to you.

If the server is outside your scope and you're only concerned with the app on your iDevice, you're probably writing a Payment Application, and you need to worry about [PA-DSS compliance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PA-DSS) instead.  That's more serious, there are no self-assessments for Payment Applications, and no organization can use an un-approved Payment Application without being in violation of the PCI DSS.